# Creating a relevant right triangle to evaluate $\sec\left(\arctan\frac{4}{3}\right)$

Tags: trigonometry, triangles, inverse-trigonometric-functions

I am trying to solve the following:

$$\sec\left(\arctan\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)\right)$$

The problem tells me to use a relevant right triangle, but I am curious as to if I need to create a right triangle for the inside ($\arctan(\frac{4}{3}))$ or the outside ($\sec$)?

Thank you.

Comment: The angle is the inside argument. That is your right triangle.

Comment: @DavidP: I would have thought that the argument of the secant would have a natural interpretation as an angle, not the argument of an arctangent.

Comment: The argument is $\tan^{-1}(4/3)$, that is the inside argument.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}
&\theta =\mathrm{arc}\tan \displaystyle\frac{4}{3}
&\\
&\tan \theta =\displaystyle\frac{4}{3}
&\\
&\sec ^2\theta =1+\tan ^2\theta =\displaystyle\frac{25}{9}
&\\
&\sec \theta =\displaystyle\frac{5}{3}\\ 
\end{align}$$
since $\theta\in(0,\pi/2)$,so wo ignore the negative value

from the value of $tan$ you can see this is a right triangle with length  $$3,4,5$$

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps. You need to consider $\angle \alpha$.

[image]